# codeigniter 4 migration file not working if having same suffix?

Tags: codeigniter, database-migration, codeigniter-4

I've just started learning about codeigniter 4. I'm trying to migrate my database but when I try to migrate the same table twice, it gives an error `Cannot declare class App\Database\Migrations\Barang, because the name is already in use`.

but none of my migration files have the same name as you can see in the image below
[image]

Answer (score 4):

##### Explanation:

When you run `php spark make:migration barang`, CodeIgniter 4 creates a **migration file** `app/Database/Migrations/2022-03-22-135842_Barang.php` having a **class name** `Barang` under the **namespace** `App\Database\Migrations`.

When you run `php spark make:migration barang` the second or third time, CodeIgniter 4 performs the **same** process as specified above except that the respective migration files will have different filenames more specifically different "timestamp prefixes".

When you now run `php spark migrate` to initiate a migration process, CodeIgniter 4 realizes that you have conflicting **class names** under the same **namespace**, hence the error.

##### Solution:

Always specify unique "migration names" when creating a new migration using the command:

`php spark make:migration unique_migration_name_here`

Most preferably, the "migration name" should briefly describe the actual intention of the migration. I.e

`php spark make:migration alter_users_rename_profile_pic_add_timestamps`

Check this answer I posted earlier:

[codeigniter 4 migration file not creating table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71636621/7376590)